# Get the JSON response from swift api call

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am bit new to swift programming with iOS. Can anyone help me to sort out the following problem. I am getting a JSON response as the following.

```
{
    "response": {
        "token": "d1fb8c33e401809691699fc3fa7dcb9b728dd50c7c4e7f34b909"
    },
    "messages": [
        {
            "code": "0",
            "message": "OK"
        }
    ]
}
```

I was trying several things to get the "token" out from this.

```
let data = json["response"] as! [[String : AnyObject]]
```

But none of these worked. Can anyone help me ? This is with swift 3

Comment: It's better to use `Codable` for parsing. You can get free code from [here](https://app.quicktype.io/).

Comment: Codable is in Swift 4+. They are using Swift 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `response` is a json object that has `token` so you need to cast `response` as `dictionary` then access `token` from it as below,

```
if let response = json["response"] as? [String : Any],
   let token = response["token"] as? String {
      print(token)
}
```

Avoid using force-unwrapping that can cause crashes.

---

Recommended way of parsing in Swift is using `Codable`. Here is the complete example,

```
// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let response: Response
    let messages: [Message]
}

// MARK: - Message
struct Message: Codable {
    let code, message: String
}

// MARK: - Response
struct Response: Codable {
    let token: String
}

do {
    let data = Data() // Change this to data from the API
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
    print(result.response.token)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: There is a slight issue regarding using the second way of JSON values parsing. It is I cannot include new plugins or extensions to the project. So I have to continue with the first way you recommended.